# Create a sfc-column from nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, vector, spatial, r-sf

So the issue is that I have a column, "location", which is a list of lists. The nested lists are of length 2 and all have at index `1` the latitude-value and at index `2` the longitude-value of a point. As I want to create a `sfc`-object from this column, I thaught about converting each nested list into a `sfg`-object in order to convert it afterwards into a `sfc`-object.

The first three nested list look like this:

```
> geometry[1:3]
[[1]]
[1] 49.45082 11.07702

[[2]]
[1] 49.45006 11.07262

[[3]]
[1] 49.45704 11.08664
```

So I'm just a little stuck and don't know how to create a `sfc`-object from this nested list. 
Any hint would be awesome!!

Comment: convert to `sfg_POINT` objects, then use `st_as_sfc` . For example `pts <- lapply( geometry, sf::st_point ); 
sfc <- sf::st_as_sfc( pts )`

Comment: thanks a lot!! Way easier than I thaught... Sorry for the naive question:/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you have is just a list of vectors with coordinates, you can use `purrr::map` or `lapply` to iterate over each and convert to a list of `sf` point objects, then convert that to an `sfc`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

coords <- list(
  c(49.45082, 11.07702),
  c(49.45006, 11.07262),
  c(49.45704, 11.08664)
)

purrr::map(coords, st_point) %>%
  st_as_sfc()
#> Geometry set for 3 features 
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 49.45006 ymin: 11.07262 xmax: 49.45704 ymax: 11.08664
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#> POINT (49.45082 11.07702)
#> POINT (49.45006 11.07262)
#> POINT (49.45704 11.08664)
```

If you have the more common form of your geometry as a data frame column, you can do the same operation to that column:

```r
dat <- tibble(geometry = coords)

dat %>%
  mutate(geometry = purrr::map(geometry, st_point) %>%
           st_as_sfc())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>              geometry
#>               <POINT>
#> 1 (49.45082 11.07702)
#> 2 (49.45006 11.07262)
#> 3 (49.45704 11.08664)
```

Or convert the whole thing to an `sf` data frame:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(geometry = purrr::map(geometry, st_point)) %>%
  st_as_sf()
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 49.45006 ymin: 11.07262 xmax: 49.45704 ymax: 11.08664
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>              geometry
#>               <POINT>
#> 1 (49.45082 11.07702)
#> 2 (49.45006 11.07262)
#> 3 (49.45704 11.08664)
```

The choice between these just depends on your use.

Comment: wow thanks alot for the answer!! do you have any ideia of how to swap the values in each nested lisk? Because I think lat and lon are at the wrong place for the `sf_point`-obejct

Comment: `st_point` assumes your coordinates are in the order (x, y). You can just call `rev` on the coordinates vectors to reverse their order

Comment: thank you very much! I tried it but didnt´'t manage to make it. Can I simply revert the final sfc-column and all it's entries?

Comment: I'm not sure. What went wrong with just reversing the vectors beforehand?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. As you sais, it turned out to be supereasy;)